# Mobile Navigation Menu Not Collapsing in Bootstrap 5.3.0 with jQuery 3.7.0

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying that when in  mobile view I click on hamburger icon the nav bar list of (Menu, About, Awards and Tel No. ) appears and disappears when clicked again. But nothing is happening whenever I click on the icon.I am Using Bootstrap 5.3.0 and jquery 3.7.0 and I have also used this code

data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" removing bs as it was changed in bootstrap 5 and it was not working. Can someone help me?

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', serif;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#logo-img {
  background: url('../images/restaurant-logo_large.png') no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
}

#Navbar-1 {
  float: right;
}

#pqp {
  float: left;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.navbar-brand h1 {
  /* Restaurant name */
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  color: #557c3e;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #222;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: .75;
}

.navbar-brand p {
  /* Kosher cert */
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .7em;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.navbar-brand p span {
  /* Star-K */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 10px;
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
}

#nav-list {
  list-style: none;
}

#nav-list a {
  color: #951C49;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

div>ul>li>a:hover {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#nav-list a span {
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

#phone {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#phone a {
  /* Phone number */
  text-align: right;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#phone div {
  /* We Deliver */
  color: #557c3e;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: larger;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle,
.navbar-header .icon-bar {
  border: 1px solid #61122f;
}

.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content="IE=edge">
  <title>David Chu's China</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/David Chu icon.png">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.css'>
</head>
<header>
  <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container" id="Navbar-1">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="Web-site(index).html" id="pqp" class="d-none d-md-block">
          <div id="logo-img" alt="Logo Image"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a href="Web-site(index).html">
            <h1 style=" margin-top: 5%;">David Chu's China Bistro</h1>
          </a>
          <p>
            <img src="images/star-k-logo.png" alt="Kosher certification">
            <span>Kosher Certified</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="button">
          <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-controls="collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="collapsable-nav" class="d-none d-md-block" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul id="nav-list" class="navbar">
          <li>
            <a href="menu-categories.html">
              <img src="images/icons8-cutlery-30.png"> <br> Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="images/icons8-about-30.png"><br> About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="images/icons8-trophy-30.png"><br> Awards</a>
          </li>
          <li id="phone">
            <a href="tel:410-602-5008">
              <span>410-602-5008</span></a>
            <div>* We Deliver</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<body>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have content in your demo outside the head and body elements. This is invalid. Please fix it so it's valid HTML and shows the problem. I see no menu icon at mobile sizes. Also tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Protips: Don't use floats for layout. Use the modern layout tools Bootstrap provides. Also, much of your CSS could be replaced with Bootstrap classes. Get to know the library better so you aren't duplicating code.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is missing bootsrap class **navbar-expand-lg** and remove class **d-none and d-md-block** for **#collapsable-nav**

```
<div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
```

Fixed code in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xeucdL8m/1/)